# Linq -- How to perform Join in ForEach statement?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

The Linq Join examples I've seen illustrate hot ti Join when creating an anonymous type. How do I do the the Join in a ForEach statement.

e.g.

```
foreach (item i in MyContext.SomeEntity.Include("NavigationProperty1").Include("NavigationProperty2").Join(MyContext.SomeEntity2 on id == id)
{
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: The question is for example syntax for the following Pseudo Code:   .Join(MyContext.SomeEntity2 on id == id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're trying to mix query syntax with just calling the extension methods directly here - that's not going to work to start with.

But the result of a join is a sequence of *pairs*, effectively - pairs which have some property in common. It's not clear where "item" comes from - how do you want each pair from `SomeEntity` and `SomeEntity2` to be transformed into an `item`?

Your call is likely to end up looking something like:

```
...Join(MyContext.SomeEntity2, x => x.id, y => y.id, (x, y) => !!!)
```

where the !!! is the projection from a pair of entities to a single useful value.

See [part 19 of my Edulinq blog series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-19-join.aspx) for more information about how the `Join` method works.